# MySQL GROUP BY not working with identical TIMESTAMPs

Tags: mysql, group-by, timestamp

I'm doing a `SELECT DISTINCT` on rows that have identical timestamps and specifying `GROUP BY`; it only finds one row, no doubt because it's disallowing duplicates.

I tried running an update to each row with `NOW()`, but `GROUP BY` is still seeing the timestamps as identical.

Any way to update all timestamps for a table while incrementing each a millisecond (or something)?

Comment: well if you use distinct and group by, it's quite normal you don't see duplicates timestamps. But as it doesn't seem so important to you (as you're willing to update it), why not simply remove the distinct and group by ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any way to update all timestamps for a table while incrementing each a
>   millisecond (or something)?

This is for updating each rows based on what you need (instead of millisecond, it increase by second)

```
SET @COUNTER = 0;
UPDATE table SET timestamp_col = NOW() 
+ INTERVAL (@COUNTER := @COUNTER + 1) SECOND;
```

but if you don't care about increase by one second, but only want unique timestamps, you can try

```
UPDATE table SET timestamp_col = NOW() + INTERVAL id SECOND;
```

Given that `id` is an auto-incremental column.

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE_ADD(timestampfield, INTERVAL '0.000001' SECOND_MICROSECOND);
```

that way you can increment microseconds in mysql